# Vue3 - script setup set default property value nested object

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I'm trying to create a component that can receive a prop that is an object.

If the object is not set, I want to define a default value for it.

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
interface LocaleText {
  text: string;
  single?: boolean;
  count?: number;
  params?: any;
}
interface Title {
  title?: LocaleText;
}
interface Filter extends Title {
  items?: string[];
}
interface Props extends Title {
  filters?: Filter[];
}
interface Data {
  selectedStatus: string;
}
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  title: (): LocaleText => ({ text: "ExampleText" }),
  filters: () => [] as Filter[],
});

function getText(text?: LocaleText): string | undefined | null {
  return text?.text ?? "null";
}
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    Example:
    {{ getText(props.title) }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Page is currently displaying "Example:null"

I could not figure out why this is happening.

Comment: What about `{{ getText(title) }}`?

Comment: I've just tested with yor suggestion but didn't work. As far i know i need to use use props.title

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: If no :title prop is passed, i want to set a default value to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#typescript-only-features) in official docs :

> As of now, the type declaration argument must be one of the following to ensure correct static analysis:
>
> - A type literal
> - A reference to an interface or a type literal in the same file

So the props should be a simple interface without extending another one :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
interface LocaleText {
  text: string;
  single?: boolean;
  count?: number;
  params?: any;
}
interface Title {
  title?: LocaleText;
}
interface Filter extends Title {
  items?: string[];
}
interface Props  {
  title:string;
  single?: boolean;
  count?: number;
  params?: any;
  filters?: Filter[];
}
interface Data {
  selectedStatus: string;
}
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  title: LocaleText => ({ text: "ExampleText" }),
  filters: () => [] as Filter[],
});

function getText(text?: LocaleText): string | undefined | null {
  return text?.text ?? "nullVal";
}
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    Example:
   {{ getText(props.title) }}
  </div>
</template>
```

[DEMO](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i din't know that i couldn't extends another interface